# Insertion of data with two buttons

Tags: php, mysql

Actually my problem is,I have fours forms in two pages. I have two buttons name **save** and **continue**. Here if I click on save button data submitted in one table and show list of details ,when I click on another button called continue it will go to another page .

Here is the following code -

```
if (isset($_POST["submit_x"]) || !empty($_POST["submit_y"])) {
//here submit_x is input name of save button and submit_y is input name of continue button

/* runs some code of insert query */
if($submit_y=="continue"){      
    header("Location: example.php");            
 }else{
   header("Location: example.php?action=list");
 }
}
```

Can any one help me please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your problem? what does not work?

Comment: when i click on save button it will go to list page , when i click on continue button it will go to next page

Comment: i define submit_x in register global variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to make clear that when you will submit the form you will insert the form step wise step or all at a time......if you will go all at a time then you have store your values in session or else if you want to go through step wise step then in second form you have to update the second step fields with the first step id.

```
 if (isset($_POST["submit_x"]) || !empty($_POST["submit_y"])) {
 $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
 $_SESSION['address']=$_POST['address']
 }
```

like this you need to store in session and take it to next step

Answer (score 1):

Create two submit inputs with the same name and different values:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Continue" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
```

the form will send the value of the clicked button:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Continue') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Continue') {
       //write code for continue part
    }
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Save'){
       //write code for Save part
    }
 }

  ?>
```